# C++ Преобразование vector<string> в int

Tags: c++, строки, vector, преобразование

У меня имеется вот такая задачка:

> Создайте вектор, хранящий десять строковых значений " zero " , " one
>   " , " . , "nine " . Используйте его в программе, преобразующей цифру в
>   соответствующее строковое представление: например, при вводе цифры 7
>   на экран должна быть выведена строка seven. С помощью этой же
>   программы , используя тот же цикл ввода, преобразуйте строковое
>   представление цифры в числовое: например, при вводе строки seven на
>   экран должна быть выведена цифра 7.

Я решил её с помощью оператора `switch`.

Мне интересно было бы узнать:

> Каким образом можно решить её по другому (без использования
>   операторов), и как преобразовать vector  в int?

Буду благодарен за информацию)

Comment: "без использования операторов" никак. Задача сводится к получению значения из вектора по его индексу и поиску элемента вектора с заданным значением (и получению его индекса, естественно). Переводить вектор, да еще и строк в int - занятие бесперспективное и странное.

Answer (score 5):

Вопрос звучит странно. *"Без опрераторов"* - без каких? Оператор сравнения, например, разрешен? :)

Не менее странно и *"как преобразовать вектор в `int`"*. В какой `int` вы хотите преобразовывать весь вектор?

Что же самой задачи, то при наличии

```
vector<string> vs{"zero","one",...,"nine"};
```

никакой `switch` не нужен: для цифры `digit` надо просто вывести `vs[digit]` (ну, или если это - символ, то вывести `vs[digit-'0']`).

Вывести цифру для строки сложнее, тут и в самом нужно что-то типа `switch` - но поиск с помощью алгоритма `find` проще и короче:

```
auto it = find(vs.begin(),vs.end(),digit_string);
if (it == va.end()) 
    cout << "Wrong string\n";
else
    cout << *it << endl;
```

Comment: Мне просто было интересно возможно ли это без операторов, а с помощью цикла, например

Comment: @Petrus можно... Но цикл - тоже операторы.

Comment: Извиняюсь за своё невежество

Comment: Да можно и без цикла :)

Comment: @Harry спасибо за информацию)

Comment: @Harry не подскажите теперь как из vector<int> в string преобразовать?:D:D

Comment: Не понял вопрос... Что у нас есть - вектор, элементы которого - что из себя представляют? что это за числа? И какую строку надо получить?

Comment: @Harry у нас есть целочисленный вектор, с теми же значениями (от 0 до 9). При вводе слова six(например) мне программа должна выдать из вектора число 6. Есть предложения в преобразовании?

Comment: Какой смысл в векторе чисел? А работать все равно надо, имея массив (вектор) строк, и выбирать по индексу - это самый простой способ. Как я написал в ответе первым. Еще раз - смысла в массиве, элементы которого равны значению индекса, нет!

Comment: @Harry Хорошo, учту. Спасибо ещё раз за помощь)